# Dataframe use first column as a heading row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list:

```
>>> s=[('id', 'email', 'timestamp'), (1, 'mark@gmail.com', datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 1, 56, 43)), (2, 'tony@bravo.com', datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 18, 1, 36))]
```

Loading it into a dataframe gives me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
    0                     1                    2
0  id                 email            timestamp
1   1         mark@gmail.com  2018-12-07 01:56:43
2   2        tony@cinely.com  2018-12-07 18:01:36
```

I know you're able to pass a heading row to the `read_csv` method but how do you do that from a straight `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `columns` parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s[1:], columns=s[0])

print(df)
   id           email           timestamp
0   1  mark@gmail.com 2018-12-07 01:56:43
1   2  tony@bravo.com 2018-12-07 18:01:36
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_index` with `T`

```
pd.DataFrame(s).T.set_index(0).T
0 id           email            timestamp
1  1  mark@gmail.com  2018-12-07 01:56:43
2  2  tony@bravo.com  2018-12-07 18:01:36
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. I've never seen the `T` used before. What's the purpose of that?

Comment: @DavidL \https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[[0]])
```